# debugger for javascript in classic eclipse for Android

Tags: javascript, android

Is there any perfect tool to debug javascript in classic eclipse for Android

Answer (score 0):

already tried jsHybugger for android? https://www.jsHybugger.com

Comment: I recommend jsHybugger, it lets you set breakpoints, singlestep, catch exceptions, and interact with the JS/DOM environment.  You can use it from Eclipse or from a Chrome or Chrome-compatible debugger on the remote desktop.  It can be used with apps that create their own webView.  However it does extensively modify the JS files (on the fly, transparently to the user) to enable all this debugging -- webKit really should support javascript debugging natively.